# Google App Engine access API Service trough VPN

Tags: google-app-engine, vpn, urlfetch

Can I create a VPN on Google Cloud Platform and access private content trough this VPN on Google App Engine? I know this can be done trough Google Compute Engine, but this is not what I want.

All of my project is on Google App Engine and I use urlfetch to get external addresses and services. Will the VPN provide some kind of path/url/ip that I can access with urlfetch to get the content accessible trough the VPN?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the flexible environment today, because that uses the underlying Compute Engine infrastructure. The standard environment doesn't yet connect to the Compute Engine network, but this is an interesting use case that we'll be thinking about.

Comment: Just read that you are using `urlfetch`. I'm not sure how `urlfetch` will interact with private networks, because of the caching proxy layer in that service.